# Only half of the notification bar is covered in iphone X in react- native

Tags: react-native-ios, iphone-x

[image]

earlier it was below the notch but now as I have added support for iphone X but now only half notification is covered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `View` in a `SafeAreaView` component provided by react-native.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View>
    .
    .
    .
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

`SafeAreaView` handles device boundaries and notch introduced from iPhone X. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)